# Drop column if it has an observation is equal to ZERO

Tags: r, filter

I have a very big dataframe with 150000 rows and 1000s columns. A subset is as follow:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c('201507', '201508', '201509', '201510', '201511', '201512', '201601', '201602', '201603'),
                 col2 = c(12, 45, 6, 23, 17, 32, 67, 23, 12),
                 col3 = c(0, 0, 12, 0, 67, 34, 87, 19, 9),
                 col4 = c(4584, 3423, 6723, 1245, 3234, 14577, 213, 557, 5677),
                 col5 = c(134, 345, 0, 23, 93, 48, 12, 21, 0))
```

I want to drop any column where:

1. it has ZERO value at any row (for example `col3` and `col5`)
2. the first row of the column is ZERO (for example only `col3).

I know this is a simple example but I have 1000s of columns

Comment: Have a look at the data.table package https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html

Comment: col2 has no zeros from what I see, col3 & col5 have zeros

Comment: `df[sapply(df, function(x){!any(x == 0)})]`

Comment: @Antonis I corrected it

Comment: Won't (2) always be taken care of by (1)?

Comment: ok @Zmnako Awrahman, I think you can go with alistaire's answer

Comment: `df[colSums(df==0)==0]`

Comment: or dplyr, if you like: `df %>% select_if(~all(.x != 0))`

Comment: I tried @alistaire solution, it worked well for first one. Thanks. But second one is different than first one, I want to drop the columns if the first value is zero, which the solution is not suitable.

Comment: Are you trying to get two different subsets? The second is `df[ , df[1, ] != 0]`